# AWS DynamoDB node.js put request doesn't put data into Dynamo table

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am using following code to ingest data to DynamoDB.

Code to read from Kinesis

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk"),
DOC = require("dynamodb-doc");
docClient = new DOC.DynamoDB();

function upsert(result) {
   var info = new Info(result);
   console.log('Within upsert :', info.AcctNo);
   docClient.putItem({
      TableName: "test_lamda_dynamo_table",
      Item: info
   }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('error', err);
        context.done('error', err);
      } else {
        console.log('success', data);
        context.done('success', event.Records);
      }
   });
}
```

I am not able to see error handler sysouts in cloudwatch logs as well as I am not able to see data in DynamoDB.

Below are sample logs from cloudwatch

```
"Within upsert Info: 1234456"
```

I am not able to see any error logs related to PutItem function in cloudwatch lambda function logs.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you test your lambda function to check if all the steps run smoothly?

Comment: I have verified same with Get request. I am able to read data from Dynamo using same lambda function.

Comment: There is a way to test the lambda function itself by pressing 'test' button, it will run the function and give you the log. You can do that and see what `console.log` gives you

Comment: I have verified it using test button. here is what I am getting in logs.
2015-10-20T08:27:48.090Z 7130dc0f-7704-11e5-90c5-d181341d7eff [ 'Within upsert meter Info: 1234456' ]
END RequestId: 7130dc0f-7704-11e5-90c5-d181341d7eff
REPORT RequestId: 7130dc0f-7704-11e5-90c5-d181341d7eff Duration: 652.26 ms Billed Duration: 700 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 37 MB

Comment: Can you check that the `docClient` is initialized and you can put something into another table, just to check?

Comment: I have verified DynamoDB access as well for lambda role.

Comment: Then it's really strange if DDB is working and you can't put an item. Can you try to put a random string to another existing table in DDB?

Comment: Tried out with another table as well. i am not able to put item in another table using same client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92831/discussion-between-chetan-shirke-and-vsevolod-goloviznin).

Comment: `dynamodb-doc` is deprecated, use DynamoDB driver in `aws-sdk`. You also need to grant your Lambda role proper permissions to access your DynamoDB table via IAM policy.

Comment: Modified permissions in lamdba role ( given dynamodb:*). Issue is fixed now. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for this problem on below link.

[Querying DynamoDB with Lambda does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739965/querying-dynamodb-with-lambda-does-nothing)

This was because of context.succeed call used in lambda handler as well.

```
    exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
    try {
      var payload = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii');

      console.log('Decoded payload:', payload);

      upsert(payload, context);

      // bug
      context.succeed("Success")

    } catch (e) {
      // log error and continue
      console.error('Error occured while inserting messages to Dynamo' + e);
    }
  });
};
```